# Div not displayed in chrome without any reason

Tags: css, google-chrome, html

I have a very strange problem I never had before. Chrome doesn't display me a div. There's nothing special with the div. It just isn't displayed.

In IE and Firefox it works as desired, just in chrome not - really strange!

```
<div id="ad-wrapper">
        <div id="vertical-ad-1" class="box">fa</div>
        <div id="vertical-ad-2" class="box">fa</div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
#ad-wrapper {
width: 170px;
margin-top: 5px;
float: left;
margin-right: 3px;
}

#vertical-ad-1 {
width: 170px;
height: 610px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#vertical-ad-2 {
width: 170px;
height: 610px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for me Firefox(V21) and Chrome (V27) look the same on my computer, and both show the div's.

Comment: Try clearing your chrome browsing data then try again.

Comment: Strange. Any idea why chrome should not display the div to me?

Comment: Done. Still not displayed

Comment: Can you provide screen shots of the expected and unexpected behaviors?  If no one can replicate it, we may be able to help by seeing it.

Comment: http://s7.directupload.net/images/130620/ajz4hbyv.png In chrome there is nothing

Comment: Ha, well, this one's on me.  I can't view that site at work.  Can you include it in your post?  Also can you include both the expected and unexpected behaviors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh it seems the the div named "ad-wrapper" was removed by ad-blocker. Renaming the div to ad-wrapperx solved the problem.